# Facebook Graph API to Pull News Feed. Replace discontinued RSS/XML

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, rss

OK, Since facebook has discontinued their RSS feed for their news feed.  I've been trying to figure out how to use Graph API to pull the newsfeed in.  I've been searching but i can not find anything. Am I doing this right? Tried going through the developer.fb docs but can't seem to get it right.  What am I doing wrong?  This is what I've done:  I created an App in developer.fb. enabled user_feed, read_stream (yes i know it is being deprecated), and user_status.  I've also enabled it or made it live.  All i want to do is put the news feed on another website.

My code is as followed (tried two methods):

`
    
        Open Graph rss

```
</head>
<body>
    <script>
        window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
            FB.init({
                appId      : 'MyAppID',
                xfbml      : true,
                version    : 'v2.4'
            });
        };

        (function(d, s, id){
            var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
            if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
            js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
            js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
            fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
        }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
    </script>

    <script>
        function feed() {
            FB.api(
                "/me/feed",
                function (response) {
                    if (response && !response.error) {
                        document.write('are we here?'); //no
                        document.write(response.data.message);
                    }
                }
            );   
        }



        function feed2(){

            var page_id = 'my_pageID';  //Also tried appid
            var pageaccessToken='MyAppToken';

            FB.api('/' + $page_id + '/feed?access_token=' + pageaccessToken, function(response){
                document.write("am i here?"); // does not get here
                if (response && response.data && response.data.length){
                    var ul = document.getElementById('pagefeed');
                    for (var j=0; j < response.data.length; j++){
                        var feed = response.data[j];
                        document.write(feed.message);
                        document.write(feed.link);
                    }
                }
            });
        }

    </script>


    <button onclick="feed()">test</button> 
    <button onclick="feed2()">feed</button>

</body>
```

`

Comment: Is it possible to do what I am trying to do?

Comment: read_stream have been deprecated and will be removed in 90 days.

Comment: So it's not possible to get the news feed?

Comment: Correct. You can not get feed

Comment: apparently you can.  Thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

Just for your information.  You actually CAN view your pages feed and it's very very simple:

https://graph.facebook.com/{Page-ID}/posts?access_token={access-Token}

You need to create a graph API app to get an access token.  but it's possible

check it:

http://johndoesdesign.com/blog/2011/php/adding-a-facebook-news-status-feed-to-a-website/